# Power button is not working properly on dell latitude e4300

Tags: dell-latitude

I have a problem with my Power button.

It starts if I press it many times or long press the button.

If I open the tray cover (under which is the power, sleep, and volume  buttons) and then press the power button my laptop turns on perfectly.

So there is only problem at the upper button, not with the inner button.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Take your computer to a repair shop and get the power button checked.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the button isn't making a clean connection. Consider looking up disassembly of the laptop in the user manual to check the connection it should be making, or taking it to a computer repair store.

Also remember that many operating systems, including Windows, have options for how the OS responds when the power button is pressed.

[image]